# How to check what user has just typed(Differentiate inputs of different symbols)?

Tags: javascript

How can I check exactly what has the user inputed instead of what key they has pressed?

I need to find out whether the user has inputted English comma (,) or the Chinese comma (，).  I tried to check it with `event.keyCode` at first, but I found out that they appear the same

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just get the value of the input and check if it's what you expected, in this case for example `if e.target.value="," `

Comment: This will get everything in the input field, but I just want to get the value of key last typed by the user.

Comment: You could get the string and test the last character.